# PerfMon Counters Not Available

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, performance, perfmon

Unless I'm going crazy here, I'm having a problem trying to load some basic counters from one of our older Windows 2003 SP2.

Let's take Page Faults/sec as an example - when I try to add the counter, it is no where to be found, especially under the "Memory" component. I'm assuming this should be there, and it seems that other scattered counters are missing.

Has anyone run into this before?

Thanks.

**Update:** Also, it does not work either locally or remotely.

Comment: are Page Faults and Cache Faults/sec equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. Been there, done that. Counters can become corrupted and unavailable. Try this to fix the problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956

Note that there is a tool to automate this process. It's called the Performance Counters Rebuild Wizard. It's an internal MS tool and not generally available for download. I was able to find and download it doing a Google search, but I no longer have or remember the URL for it. A Google search might turn it up for you.

Comment: Thanks... I'll take a look. 

I did the manual rebuild a few months ago, but gave up with no positive results.

Comment: It can be tricky. The wizard really helps if you can find it.

Comment: Found it. I hope this is legit. Use at your own discretion. http://www.filestube.com/2a5829e0d939a74203ea,g/Performance-Counters-Rebuild-Wizard.html

Comment: Also, my intention here is not to post anything illegal or unethical. If anyone can weigh in on this, please do so. I know this tool is a MS PSS tool not generally available for download to the public but the link I posted is where I found it and downloaded it from.

Comment: Caution and disclaimer noted. I'll try to do it manual first anyway.

Comment: never did get it working again. After doing the manual process, all the SQL and .NET connectors were hosed. As I began repairing them, I used the tool instead and everything went back to the original problem. 

This server is old and I've put in a request for a rebuild - at least then I can put it together properly and monitor correctly. 

Thanks for the input.

Comment: I think the fix for SQL and .NET (I may have read this is another article) is to reinstall your .NET applications and may be to run a repair on SQL server. I had a similar problem with Exchange server, when I rebuilt the default system counters I lost the Exchange counters. Reinstalling SP2 for Exchange fixed that.